# How to vertically center <div> inside the parent element with CSS?

Tags: css, alignment, centering

I'm trying to make a small username and password input box.

I would like to ask, how do you vertically align a div?

What I have is:

```
<div id="Login" class="BlackStrip floatright">
   <div id="Username" class="floatleft">Username<br>Password</div>
   <div id="Form" class="floatleft">
   <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" border="0"><br>
      <input type="password" border="0">
   </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the div with id Username and Form to vertically align itself to the center? I've tried to put:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

in CSS for the div with id Login, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css

Answer (score 284, accepted):

The best approach in modern browsers is to use flexbox:

```
#Login {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Some browsers will need vendor prefixes.  For older browsers without flexbox support (e.g. IE 9 and lower), you'll need to implement a fallback solution using one of the [older methods](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2744005/2).

**Recommended Reading**

- [Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)
- [A Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- [Using CSS Flexible Boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

Comment: To align horizontally, I added `justify-content: center` as well. (Not quite the same scenario though.)

Comment: There is also `display: inline-flex` in case you want the parent element to stay, well, inline :)

Comment: To stack divs one on top of the other, use `flex-direction: column`

Comment: Flex is the worst method I've ever seen, so much pain with Bootstrap that I would more likely use Javascript over this ...

Comment: Note: be careful if you are trying to centre anything with a 'display: inline-box'. The line-height of the contents can cause extra space below the inline-box, and the result is that the child is aligned slightly above centre. I am not sure what part of the html spec causes this, but I found it to be unobvious and it took a while to work out the reason that the children of the flexbox were not properly centred vertically.

Comment: won't work on IE.

Comment: For me, just 2 more properties were required to make it work, 
```display: flex;
flex-direction: column;```

Comment: You literally saved my life. My boss, CJ, said if I don't get this done today I'm in big trouble. Also @meshy that worked like a charm ty

Answer (score 112):

This can be done with 3 lines of CSS and is compatible back to (and including) IE9:

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cas07zq8/

[credit](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

Comment: This is my personal favorite, especially when I can use it as a LESS or SASS mix-in.

Comment: Breaks responsive design

Comment: Can you provide an example of how and why it breaks "responsive design" as a whole? Whether or not it breaks responsive design is a matter of your project's structure already in my opinion.

Comment: How about when you don't know the height?

Answer (score 83):

You can vertically align a div in another div. See [this example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktxpP/3/) or consider the example below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="innerDiv"> My Vertical Div </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outerDiv {
    display: inline-flex;  // <-- This is responsible for vertical alignment
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

.innerDiv {
    margin: auto 5px;   // <-- This is responsible for vertical alignment
    background-color: green;   
}
```

The `.innerDiv`'s margin must be in this format: `margin: auto *px;`

[Where, `*` is your desired value.]

`display: inline-flex` is supported in the latest (updated/current version) browsers with HTML5 support.

***It may not work in Internet Explorer :P :)***

Always try to define a height for any vertically aligned div (i.e. innerDiv) to counter compatibility issues.

Comment: M not so good with CSS, but out of so many solutions I came across, this one worked for me the best.

Comment: This doesn't work in IE browser.

Comment: display:flex  does the job without breaking something.

Comment: @SteveBreese stop using ie. 
http://breakupwithie8.com/

Comment: not compatible with IE9

Comment: This solution only works if you add the parts noted as being responsible for vertical alignment, AND the height on the outerDiv. Without the height, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 14):

I'm pretty late to the party, but I came up with this myself and it's one of my favorite quick hacks for vertical alignment. It's crazy simple, and easy to understand what's going on.

You use the `:before` css attribute to insert a div into the beginning of the parent div, give it `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle` and then give those same properties to the child div. Since `vertical-align` is for alignment along a line, those inline divs will be considered a line.

Make the `:before` div `height:100%`, and the child div will automatically follow and align in the middle of a very tall "line."

```
.parent:before, .child {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.parent:before {
    content:""; // so that it shows up
    height:100%; // so it takes up the full height
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aor3dk24/1/) to demonstrate what I'm talking about. The child div can be any height, and you never have to modify its margins/paddings.
And [here's a more explanatory fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aor3dk24/20/).

If you're not fond of `:before`, you can always manually put in a div.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="before"></div>
    <div class="child">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

And then just reassign `.parent:before` to `.parent .before`

Comment: That's brilliant! First time I see it and I really wonder why as it's perfect. I've modified the CSS selector to .parent > * so I don't need a child selector anymore. That means I can use the class everywhere! I'd +1000

Comment: Awesome! But, why we need to insert a div before, instead to vertical-align directly the child div? (I see it not work, but why?)

Comment: I was able to use this technique to include a secondary child div inside of the "child" div in the example. A media rule in my CSS file lets me then show the new child-child content to the right of the original content on wide screens and below it and smaller on narrow screens, and it's all still vertically centered. In other words, this works for me with more than just some text in that "child" div.

Answer (score 11):

If you know the height, you can use absolute positioning with a negative `margin-top` like so:

```
#Login {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-200px; /* width / -2 */
    margin-top:-200px; /* height / -2 */
}
```

Otherwise, there's no real way to vertically center a div with just CSS

Answer (score 7):

In my firefox and chrome work this:

CSS:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;     // vertical align
align-items: center;         // horizontal align
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this site useful: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/
This worked for me:

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent {
    padding: 5% 0;
}

#child {
    padding: 10% 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@GáborNagy's comment on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046395/vertical-align-a-div-with-dynamic-height-inside-another-div) was the simplest solution I could find and worked like a charm for me, since he brought a jsfiddle I'm copying it here with a small addition:

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    height: 150px;
    width: 800px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="cell">
        <div class="content">
            Content goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you wish to also align it horizontally you'd have to add another div "inner-cell" inside the "cell" div, and give it this style:

```
#inner-cell{
      width: 250px;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vertically aligning  has always been tricky.

Here I have covered up some method of vertically aligning a div.

http://jsfiddle.net/3puHE/

### HTML:

```
<div style="display:flex;">

<div class="container table">
<div class="tableCell">
<div class="content"><em>Table</em> method</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container flex">
<div class="content new"><em>Flex</em> method<br></div>
</div>

<div class="container relative">
<div class="content"><em>Position</em> method</div>
</div>

<div class="container margin">
<div class="content"><em>Margin</em> method</div>
</div>

</div>
```

### CSS:

```
em{font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;}
.container {
    width:200px;height:200px;background:#ccc;
    margin: 5px; text-align: center;
}
.content{
    width:100px; height: 100px;background:#37a;margin:auto;color: #fff;
}
.table{display: table;}
.table > div{display: table-cell;height: 100%;width: 100%;vertical-align: middle;}
.flex{display: flex;}
.relative{position: relative;}
.relative > div {position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;}
.margin > div {position:relative; margin-top: 50%;top: -50px;}
```

Comment: working jsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/breese/3puHE/10/

Comment: why is the my link above not working?

Comment: All the boxes (HTML, JavaScript, CSS) are empty.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/dvL512e7/

Unless the aligned div has fixed height, try using the following CSS to the aligned div:

```
{
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: table;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox (tested on version 40), although works with `img` tag in place of `div`.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to specify min-height

```
#login
    display: flex
    align-items: center
    justify-content: center
    min-height: 16em
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using fix height div than you can use padding-top according your design need.
or you can use top:50%. if we are using div than vertical align does not work so we use padding top or position according need.

Answer (score 0):

Centering the child elements in a div. It works **for all screen sizes**

```css
#parent {
  background-color: red;
  height: 160px;
  
  display: flex;
  
  /*vertical-align */
  align-items: center;
  
   /*horizontal align*/
  justify-content: center;
}
    
#child {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

simplest way to center your div element is to use this class with following properties.

```
.light {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    border: 3px solid green;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a way that works great for me. The next script inserts an invisible image (same as bgcolor or a transparant gif) with height equal to half the size of the white-space on the screen. The effect is a perfect vertical-alignment.

Say you have a header div (height=100) and a footer div (height=50) and the content in the main div that you would like to align has a height of 300:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var screen = window.innerHeight;
var content = 150 + 300;
var imgheight = ( screen - content) / 2 ;
document.write("<img src='empty.jpg' height='" + imgheight + "'>"); 
</script>
```

You place the script just before the content that you want to align!

In my case the content I liked to align was an image (width=95%) with an aspect ratio of 100:85 (width:height).Meaning the height of the image is 85% of it's width. And the Width being 95% of the screenwidth.

I therefore used:

```
var content = 150 + ( 0.85 * ( 0.95 * window.innerWidth ));
```

Combine this script with

```html
<body onResize="window.location.href = window.location.href;">
```

and you have a smooth vertical alignment.

Hope this works for you too!

Answer (score -3):

have you try this one?

```
.parentdiv {
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
 height: 300px; // at least you have to specify height
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score -5):

divs can't be vertically aligned that way, you can however use margins or position:relative to modify its location.