# Center a 'div' vertically in a % height 'div'

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to center a *div* vertically in a % height *div*?

Comment: Related (but not an exact dupe): [Vertically Aligning Divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743989/vertically-aligning-divs).

Comment: Please check those links http://jsfiddle.net/ERuX4/1/ http://stackoverflow.com/a/10010055/1312610

Comment: Here is a example working for IE, Firefox and Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/ETKhu/ Probably you need for future work :)

Comment: Working example. Easier way to do the same: [jsfiddle.net/NT8Mn](http://jsfiddle.net/NT8Mn)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This has been asked enough times here as well as all over the Internet.

A quick search will bring you tons of results. Anyhow, my preferred way of doing this is to use `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;`. See [this page](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html) for an example. (Beware that this doesn't work on [Internet Explorer 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6).)

Comment: yeah, i did search the internet,
However there were so many results that i had no idea which ones were valid, and which ones were old hat.

Cheers.

Comment: Also, another way to do this without complicated CSS. Try this: 

[jsfiddle.net/NT8Mn](http://jsfiddle.net/NT8Mn)

Comment: I searched the internet and this was the top result.

Answer (score 6):

If your inner *div* has an absolute height (let’s say 100 pixels), you could do this:

```
.outerdiv{
  position: relative; // Or absolute, or fixed
  height: 80%;
}

.innerdiv{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;  // It's at 50%, but not really centered
  margin-top: -50px; // So just move it up by the half of its height :D
}
```

I don't like this solution very much, and I'm sure there are a lot of other possibilities (maybe using tables or `display: table-cell;`) - but this is the first that comes into my mind...

Answer (score 3):

```
.outerdiv {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Warning - it will *not* work in all browsers!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any need for px units.

Change `top`, `bottom`, `right`, `left` or use percentages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    bottom: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    text-align: center;
                    white-space: nowrap;
                    overflow: hidden;">
            <div style="position: relative;
                        display: inline-block;
                        height: 100%;
                        vertical-align: middle;"></div>
            <div style="background-color: #FEEF88;
                        position: relative;
                        display: inline-block;
                        vertical-align: middle;">Hola todo el mundo :D</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the following technique, which involves two containers:

### The outer container:

- should have `display: table;`

### The inner container:

- should have `display: table-cell;`
- should have `vertical-align: middle;`

### The content box:

- should have `display: inline-block;`

You can add any content you want to the content box without caring about its width or height!

Also, you can easily add horizontal centering by adding `text-align: center;` to your inner container.

### **Demo:**

```css
body {
    margin : 0;
}

.outer-container {
    position : absolute;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
}

.inner-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.centered-content {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    padding : 20px;
    border : 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
   <div class="inner-container">
     <div class="centered-content">
        Malcolm in the Middle
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/L1jwLo5c/)!