# vertically center select in div

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [center div vertically in a % height div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363562/center-div-vertically-in-a-height-div)

I am trying to use the solution here: [center div vertically in a % height div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363562/center-div-vertically-in-a-height-div)

however I want the header to be at the top of the div and that solution puts the header centered with the select...

What I want is the header to remain at the top, and the select to be vertically and horizontally centered and the total height of the outside div to be 100px.

What I tried is on the fiddle below...

jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/K8wWa/1/

Comment: The `div` with `display:table-cell` in your example needs an explicit width like `height:100px`.

Comment: I added that in: http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/K8wWa/3/ I don't see a change

Comment: @kralco626: See it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/svmEt/),  had to float the `h3` too.

Comment: Marcel : your inner div has a 100px height, kralco wants a 100% height div.

Comment: This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/svmEt/2/ but it's not horizontally centered...

Comment: and why the vote to close without a comment saying why :(???

Comment: Here is a example working for IE, Firefox and Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/ETKhu/ Probably you need for future work :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the partial solution in the comments :

Look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svmEt/5/)

To have horizontal align, you'll have to put your `display:table-cell` div in a `display:table` div.

since we can't trust jsFiddle to always be around, here's the result:

```
<div id="d1">
    <h3>header</h3>
    <div id="table">
        <div id="d2">
            <select><option>Status</option></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
div#d1 {height:100px;width:100%;border:2px solid black}

div#table {display:table; width:100%;text-align:center}
div#d2 {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:80px;
}

h3{background:red;text-align:center}
```