# HTML Vertical Align

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, vertical-alignment

What is the quickest way for me to get a div vertically centered - Cross browser?

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <header>
            blah
            </header><!-- End header -->
        </div><!-- End mainContainer -->

</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
#mainContainer{
    width:960px;
    margin:60px auto;
    background:#FFF;
    border:1px solid black;
}
header{
    padding:30px 0 30px 0;
    background:red;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Please use easy way

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10010055/1312610

http://jsfiddle.net/ERuX4/1/

Comment: Hey.  What do the - 200 represent I have a box 600px wide and its off center

Comment: I have edited your code please check, http://jsfiddle.net/e2bmC/1/
please copy the code and paste on your dreamwear and check it

Comment: Hey,I am a bit confused about what I should be setting here http://cl.ly/1A2X0A1f2z351w3w3j3g gets me http://cl.ly/0k0y3I372x2A3l1E0K3q

Comment: It was a easy and useful code in more situations , please set border after you can identify how is working

Answer (score 2):

If you can specify a height, then you can use

```
position:absolute
top:50%;
left:50%;
width:200px;
height:200px;
margin-left:-100px;
margin-top:-100px;
```

where the negative margins are half of the width and height respectively

Comment: Looks like left:50% didn't take. The parent element that you want to center it inside of needs to have a position:relative declared, but if you're just centering relative to 'body' you don't need to do that.

If you post it somewhere where I can see the code I can probably tell you what's up. http://jsfiddle.net/