# Vertical center an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use the line-height, vertical-align method to center an image inside a div. Looking at examples, questions on here, and other fixes they all suggest and even show that this works. Yet it's not working for me.

Basic structure

```
<div class="photo_container">
    <img alt="" src="photos/1.jpg" class="thumbnail" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.photo_container
{
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: White;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #AAA;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 160px;
}
img.thumbnail
{
    vertical-align: middle;   
}
```

Basically, the container is always 160px high as you can see, but the image inside could be something like 100px high. In this case I want there to be 30px spacing at the top and the bottom of the container and for my image to be vertically aligned in the middle.

What am I missing?

**ANSWERED**

Turns out it was a DOCTYPE problem, I was using the

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

when I should have been using the HTML 5 doctype

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Ah, in that case simply a matter of "almost standards mode" vs strict "standards mode". http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/ Using the Strict XHTML doctype declaration would also have sufficed, but it's unlikely you truly have a reason to use XHTML over ordinary HTML, and HTML5 intermingles them much anyways.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10010055/1312610

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A doctype declaration: `<!doctype html>`

(Or, alternatively: [valid code](http://validator.w3.org/))

Comment: Yup that's it. No set height width required.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work for me in chrome.. fiddle below.  Is there something I'm missing?

Edit: I did add a width/height to the non-existant image.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMAEH/)

Comment: There's something *he*'s missing. :p

Comment: Thanks, but it a static width or height doesn't change it.

Answer (score 0):

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/

This should explain how to do it.

Comment: If you looked through the whole article it doesn't just apply to background images, the concept works with divs too.  Oh well can't win them all.

Comment: I'll put you back to zero since this is a legitimate solution to the initial problem. I was however, looking for a way to get my current solution working properly.

Comment: Appreciate it, I looked at it from the approach that sometimes we try to fix something that will never be quite right, so we need to look at it from a different angle.  HTML and CSS can be such a beast in that it should work but just doesn't so we need to restructure.  My bad

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me more or less

See in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uFAK7/7/)

**CSS**

```
div.photo_container
{
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: White;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #AAA;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 160px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
img.thumbnail
{
    vertical-align: middle;   
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="photo_container">
    <img alt="" src="http://www.totalesl.com/images/icon/funny-icon.jpg" class="thumbnail" />
</div>​
```

Comment: But what about when the images he is trying to center are not 100px; he said they could be, but it sounds as if they are variable sizes, which means you need something flexible

Comment: @user1357437 the width doesn't matter, I wanted to shrink the SO logo, updated the answer with a smaller image, it still works

Comment: I saw the added width: 100px and my brain tied it to where he said the height is sometimes 100px.

Comment: @user1357437 yep the brain has mysterious ways tricking us :)