# How to center a div inside of a masonry layout?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I've searched EVERYWHERE and can't find an answer for this.

How can I vertically and horizontally center a div in a masonry layout? I basically want everything to build around this div.

Any help would be great!

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10010055/1312610

Comment: You want to have one of the items masonry always has a central layout inside container (relative to the others items)? Or you want to masonry root-container was centered?

Answer (score 12):

When you call masonry you can use the  `isFitWidth: true` and also then set margin: 0 auto on the container.

```
$container.masonry({
    columnWidth : 120,
    isFitWidth: true

});
```

See example live here : **[Centered Masonry](http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/centered.html)**

Answer (score 3):

if it's just a div you could try to user

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

for the horizontal centering.

to center vertically you could try this:

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried this prior to asking this question

Comment: so can you show the code you've already got ? It is possible to center it. (if you look at the examples of the plugin, you'll see that there are actually some sites that do it.)

Comment: None of the examples have a perfectly centered div in the middle. Some use the "cornerstamp" and some just appear to be centered. I'll work more on my code and I will post it tomorrow

Comment: @VinceV. your link went dead some time ago