# Cannot center Logo Image Vertically in a div

Tags: css

How in the world do I center an Image vertically inside a div in this case. It wont budge no matter how much I try. Can you help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> New Document </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://onr.com/css/nav.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>

<body>

<header>

<div class="cont">

    <div class="logo">
        <img src="/css/logo.png">
    </div>

    <div class="me">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Sign In</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">|</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: "proxima-nova",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.cont{

background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #34495E;
height:50px;
}


.me {
    float:right;
}

.me ul {
    float:right;
    list-style: none outside none;
}

.me li  {
    float:left;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.me li  a{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    text-decoration:none;
}

.me li  a:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
}

.logo {
    float:left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}

.logo img {
    display: block; margin: auto ;
}
```

**Image** The Image is here, but it's white.

[image]

Comment: Remove float:left  on .logo  class

Comment: @ShibinRagh If I do that, the link on side get messed up.

Comment: @jmenezes Make a fiddle let us check it

Comment: @jmenezes Your title says `vertical`. you say `horizontal`. What is the actual effect to achieve ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10010055/1312610

Comment: @GaurangTandon Vertical. That's the result of breaking your head on something for too long.

Comment: @jmenezes Should have told before. Ignore my answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it useful? I have changed some area [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/enNuN/)

html

```
 <div class="logo">
        <span><img src="http://placehold.it/50x10"></span>
    </div>


.logo{
    float:left;
}
.logo span{
    height:50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;

}

.logo img {

}
```

Comment: Did you check jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

you are using `display:table-cell` property but you didn't implelement `display:table`.

Here is the modified CSS. and working Demo. http://jsbin.com/sipajopa/1/

```
body {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: "proxima-nova",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.cont{

background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #34495E;
height:50px;
  display:table; /*Added line*/
  width:100%; /*Added line*/
}


.me {
    display: table-cell; /*Added line*/
}

.me ul {
    float:right;
    list-style: none outside none;
}

.me li  {
    float:left;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.me li  a{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    text-decoration:none;
}

.me li  a:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
}

.logo {
    display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo img {
    display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This should do it](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/L8Tbt/)

Changes:

1. Removed `.logo` rules.
2. Added `text-align:center;` to `div.cont`.

CSS code:

```
body {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: "proxima-nova",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.cont{

background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #34495E;
height:50px;
    text-align:center;
}


.me {
    float:right;
}

.me ul {
    float:right;
    list-style: none outside none;
}

.me li  {
    float:left;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.me li  a{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    text-decoration:none;
}

.me li  a:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
}


.logo img {
    display: block; margin: auto ;
}
```

So easy!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this. It will do it**

**CSS**

```
    body {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: "proxima-nova",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.cont{

background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #34495E;
height:50px;
}


.me {
    float:right;
}

.me ul {
    float:right;
    list-style: none outside none;
}

.me li  {
    float:left;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.me li  a{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    text-decoration:none;
}

.me li  a:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
}

.logo {
    float:left;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="cont">

    <div class="logo">
        <img src="Path to your image">
    </div>

    <div class="me">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Sign In</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">|</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The margin-left works here. But not the vertical align.

Comment: The vertical align problem is solved there Brother. Copy my code and see the difference