# Vertical align center in div

Tags: html, alignment, center

I have this code and i cannot vertical align content in second div to center.

```
<div style="min-height: 317px"> <!-- this min div is auto generated-->
    <div class="verticalalign">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How CSS for class `.verticalalign` i must write to vertical align center for second div ? 
Parental div i can't modify, it will be generated from theme shortcode.

I also need to horizontal text align in child div.

Comment: To align text horizontally use `text-align:` [left or center or right]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22471510/1312610

Comment: try this : `.verticalalign{
 text-align: center;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vertical-align` works with table elements only, so:

```
.fusion-column-wrapper {background: #eee; display: table; width: 100%;}
.verticalalign {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xcgjkm8v/

See that the valid value of `vertical-align` is `middle`, not `center`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make center without giving css to main div like following:

```css
.verticalalign{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div style="min-height: 317px"> 
    <div class="verticalalign">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: i need to vertical align text started by "Spojte se s budoucností" in gray background

Comment: yes, but left and right margins/padding are too big.

Comment: It is because width:50% comes from outside. Check http://i.stack.imgur.com/p3IHA.png