# center the content in a div

Tags: css, media-queries

I have 4 divs in my .html:

```
<div id="div"> 
     <div class="contenido">1</div>
</div>
<div id="divSupIzq"> 
     <div class="contenidos"><div id="textoDinamico">120 </div><div id="textoEstatico">KM/H</div></div>
</div>
    <div id="divSupDer"> 
    <div class="contenidos">zona de</br>avisos</div>
    </div>
<div id="divInfIzq"> 
    <div class="contenidos">zona de</br>informaci&oacute;n</div>
</div>
```

In .css, I've applied **border-radius** in order to give these divs circular form.
I've applied **text-align:center** because I want the content of each div being centered
But how to center the content in the height?? I give some **margin-top** in .css, but it's wrong, because the interface is adaptable to the size screens (responsible design - css queries) and margin-top isn't sufficient for me...
I don't know if I'm explaining myself well...I try that yes.
Sorry for my bad english. Regards, Daniel

**Live example**: http://jsfiddle.net/cN2pS/
Another question: what tools do you use in order to test these type of apps for differents resolutions?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: possible duplicate of [center div vertically in a % height div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363562/center-div-vertically-in-a-height-div)

Comment: Don't know if is exactly the same. But with those options, I don't solve my issue.

Comment: Thanks friend, but with that I don't solve it.

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net for your layout? That would also help everyone fix your issue or show you a working solution.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to do it right now. Sorry! :-D

Comment: Something like this... http://jsfiddle.net/cN2pS/  What I want is center the number 1 of the center circle, in all devices... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Full screen: http://jsfiddle.net/cN2pS/embedded/result/

Comment: One question about jsfiddle....how many time a example like I just created, keep in internet? Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use a table and set the align for each td center

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td align="center">
        Your text or elements
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or set the `div` display as `table-cell`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't solve the issue. Look at my post, i just edited.