# Vertical Align a DIV with dynamic height inside another DIV

Tags: css, html

I have been looking around and seem to find lots about aligning a div vertically however not with a dynamic height div surrounding it.. i have a moch up of what i require, built from all sorts of different templates i have found.. i just cant get it to do what I want maybey i am totally wrong?.. i thought it would be simple however has turned south.. i am hoping somone on here can understand what i mean and fix it easily as I am lost... tried so many different things however just end up back to square one..

I have checked out "vertically-center-content-with-css" at vdotmedia and this is exactly what i need the div to do however i can't get it working in the template i have come up with.. i do want it to be cross browser and ie6 would be nice but at least ie7..

Thanks in advanced!

The code was a bit long for here so see the link for what i am after..
http://www.mmageardirect.com.au/tmp/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

Not so easy but check this out: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Try using `vertical-align: middle` and a set of divs with `display:table`, `table-row`, `table-cell`.

Comment: wow, this was asked on 28th october 2010. Hope he already found a solution ;-)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gabor_nagy/ekHsv/1/

Tested in IE8, latest Chrome and FF at the time.

Comment: Your link is dead, but @GáborNagy's comment worked like a miracle to me