# Center Aligning A Floated DIV Vertically

Tags: html, css

I've been working on something, and am stuck on some CSS problem.  I have this:

http://sharepress.atwebpages.com/temp/

As you can see, there are two items being listed with crosses next to them.  On the second item listed, you can see it is a multiline paragraph.  I wanted to know how to vertically center align the 'x' vertically for multiline paragraphs like this.

Thank you all for your help and time :-)

Comment: This will be useful for you surely :) http://stylizedweb.com/2008/02/01/vertical-align-div/

Comment: make position relative of parent "li". make posiiton absolute of cross mark & give top:50% & margin-top: half of cross icon height.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained.  Now that you've fixed your problem the link will soon be gone along with any future usefulness of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds pretty much like the same problem as this. Depends on your browser support, but display: table-cell is a pretty good way for newer browsers. More details on the answers here.

[Vertical Align a DIV with dynamic height inside another DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046395/vertical-align-a-div-with-dynamic-height-inside-another-div)

if the X is constant height(eg 20px here), you could just give the container div `position:relative` and the x `position:absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -10px;`

So in your example something like

```
.taskItemLi {
  position:relative;
}
.delbtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  right: 0;
}
```