# Align on top and on bottom in the DIV

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I have DIVs with some text and a button in them. I need to:

- align the button on the bottom of DIV
- align the text on the top of DIV

Here is an image of what I want it to look like:

[image: alignment example]

The code I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        <p>Some text</p>
        <a type="button" class="btn" href="#">Button</a>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <p>The big one text</p>
        <a type="button" class="btn" href="#">Button</a>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <p>Some small text</p>
        <a type="button" class="btn" href="#">Button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    display: table;
}
.cell {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    height: auto;
}
.cell .btn {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: hi.. You should take a look here. This might help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743989/vertically-aligning-divs

Comment: is your div height is fixed?

Comment: @RiteshChandora No, they are not.

Comment: @ba1ar Thanks I'll read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.table {
    display: table;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    height: auto;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding-bottom:40px;
    position:relative;
}
.cell .btn {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/bukaxiyo/1/)

try this. adjust the padding according to your button height

Comment: @Irina Note that according to **[spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position)**, the effect of `position: relative` on `table-cell` is **undefined**. Hence the absolutely positioned elements will be positioned relative to their nearest containing block, which is the *initial containing block* (the `<html>`) in this example. Check the [demo](http://jsbin.com/bukaxiyo/1/) link on Firefox to verify that.

Comment: @HashemQolami Hm. Thanks. In the whole page it still work for me without `position: relative` on table-cell (but I'm not sure why).

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/epwu7/1/)

```
   .cell p{
    vertical-align: top;
    display:inline;
}

.cell .btn {
    display:block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Note:i have added two `display` properties along with `vertical-alignment`,because `p` always starts in a newline,so inorder for the `vertcal-alignment:top` to work you need to add `display:inline` for the `p` element

Comment: it doenst work if div heights are variable length..  see tb link http://jsfiddle.net/epwu7/2/

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/licoyoki/1/)

try this one,this is the simplest just copy and paste replace your code

Comment: Thanks a lot, but unfortunatelly if to add width in px to .table, and width in % to .cell, it doesn't works..

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
.cell .btn {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```