# Data-content text styling and positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a div with data-content in it that is used for hover effect. It looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div data-content="TEXT THAT NEEDS TO BE POSITIONED" class="teamleft">
</div>
```

Thanks to stackoverflow I found neat css code that uses :after and :hover:after to make hover effect possible. The only thing I can't figure out is positioning and styling the data-content text. I want to vertically center my text. Also, how do I add differently styled text in one data-content? Or maybe I should use two different data-contents?

CSS:

```
teamleft
{
position: absolute;
width:50%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #25335a;
}
.teamleft:after
{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
content: attr(data-content);
color:#fff;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
opacity:0;
transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.teamleft:hover:after
{
opacity:1;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e8t2gcxg/3/

Comment: The positioning and styling is handled right there in the `.teamleft:after` selector. Just add the relevant CSS properties. Otherwise, it might help if you explain what part of styling and/or positioning you're having troubles with.

Comment: It seems like .teamleft:after selector is for the hover block. The position of text that is inside of data-content doesn't change, except for text-align style. I am confused, sorry.

Comment: You have to explain **exactly** what it is that you're trying to do. You can't target the text independently of the `:after` pseudoelement, but you can control padding, line-height etc. Depending on what you want to do, it might or might not be possible with your current setup - but because we don't actually know what you want to do, it's impossible to say.

Comment: I wan't to vertically center my text.

Comment: ok, thanks for posting that in comment, but please post in question too. It will make more people see it.

Comment: @BarneyStinson do you know to accept an answer? You can only accept one. Click the check mark that appears when you hover beside the answer of your choice. You will gain a badge and 2 points. The person who answered gets 15. So get answering!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
.teamLeft:after {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
top:calc(50% - 10px);
content: attr(data-content);
text-align:center;
color:#fff;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
opacity:0;
transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Change the height of the `:after` to `20px;` then use top and change it to `50%` of parent div height `-10px` (half the height of the `:after`). Apply `text-align:center;` to center the text horizontally.

**edit**

See this link; it should help.

http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Link found from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2744005/3011082

Comment: It does center text, but I need a 100% height div

Comment: oh, I remember reading somewhere a way to do it... let me do some research. You'll have your answer in 12 hours.

Comment: I have tried methods from http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html and it doesn't work. I don't know, maybe it's not possible in my setup.

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper div.

```css
.teamleft
{
position: absolute;
width:300px;  
height: 30px;
background-color: #25335a;
}
.teamleft:after
{
position:absolute;
width: 300px;
height: 30px;   
content: attr(data-content);
color:#fff;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
opacity:0;
transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.teamleft:hover:after
{
opacity:1;
}

#wrapper{background-color: #25335a;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;}
p{margin-left:50px;
top:calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<p data-content="TEXT THAT NEEDS TO BE POSITIONED" class="teamleft">
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the content centered vertically and horizontally by wrapping `.teamleft` with another block element as a flex-container (`.flexShell`) and adding another class (`.flexItem`) to `.teamleft`. `.flexItem` properties allow it to be centered within it's new parent `.flexShell`.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/e8t2gcxg/9/)

[**FULLSCREEN**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/e8t2gcxg/9/embedded/result/)

### HTML

```
<main class="flexShell">
    <div data-content="TEXT THAT IS POSITIONED DEAD CENTER! THIS ADDED TEXT IS TO TEST THE WIDTH AND WRAPPING CAPABILITIES" class="teamleft flexItem">
   </div>
</main>
```

### CSS

References to the style properties used are provided in the comments.

```
/*=-=-[ RESET PROPERTIES ]-=-=*/
/* http://goo.gl/3ed2H */
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font: 500 16px/1.5 Consolas;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
/*=-=-[ FLEXBOX CLASSES ]-=-=*/
/* https://goo.gl/WySM2z */
.flexShell {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: none;
}
.flexItem {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow-y: none;
}
/*=-=-[ TEAMLEFT ]-=-=*/
.teamleft {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50vw;           /* http://goo.gl/DkXR5F */
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #25335a;
}
.teamleft:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;             /* https://goo.gl/S1mNoN */
    top: 50%;
    content: attr(data-content);
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;             
    background-color: transparent;
    display: table-cell;      /* https://goo.gl/lzmCyg */
    overflow-y: none;        /* https://goo.gl/o1Oqbf */
}
.teamleft:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```