# How to vertically center align a div with 100% width and defined padding-bottom on the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following div.

```
.div {
width:100%;
padding-bottom:20%;
background-color:blue;
}

<div class="div"></div>
```

I have been trying for a long while now to find a way to vertically fix this div at the very center of the webpage but couldn't find anything satisfactory. To be clear this completely responsive div must not move when you scroll up and down the webpage and should be fixed in the very center of the webpage with equal amount of space above and below it. Can anyone help?

Comment: this might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743989/how-to-vertically-center-divs

Comment: I assumed simple case based on your markup, but if you could give a picture, whether screenshot or mockup, it would help clarify your design intent. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should give it a `position: fixed;` to keep it in position when you start to scroll. Next, give make it 20% away from the edges by making top and bottom 20%.

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  bottom: 20%;
  width:100%;
  padding-bottom:20%;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Passes the zoom test, but fails the responsive test.. does not maintain 20% top&bottom padding when resolution changes, and content gets really short when viewing in portrait mode (phone size).

Comment: Ah, you mean margin 20% margin on either side, I changed it. Is this what you mean?

Comment: My apologies, I think I was viewing previous version of your answer.. looks good after reloading page.

Comment: You just need to deal with overflowing content in the div with `overflow:auto` or whatever

Comment: No problem. Didn't write any code for the content indeed, but I hope you'll manage Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vh` to center to viewport.

Remove the `padding` from your div and use `margin-top: 20vh`

To wit:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 20vh;
  height: 60%;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content-text {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Aria, sans-serif;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-text">
    <i>Cited from <a href="http://www.lipsum.com/" target=_blank>http://www.lipsum.com/</a></i>
    <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    <h2>Why do we use it?</h2>
    <p>
      It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
      content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various
      versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    </p>
    <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
    <p>
      Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
      one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
      Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line
      in section 1.10.32.
    </p>
    <p>
      The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
      from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
    </p>
    <h3>Where can I get some?</h3>
    <p>
      There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum,
      you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary
      of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```